# how to refer data in column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select data in column but column value is not equal to ' ' and value='NA'. In my table some column are empty. I want to filter all non-empty columns and columns have data value!='NA'.

How to write query for this requirement.

I have 200 columns in table, so that I can't refere one by one column name. Is there any keyword for column_name?

Comment: Do you don't want the columns at all those who have empty or 'NA' values or just don't want the rows containing those values ?

Comment: I want only the columns that have data except 'NA' columns

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where columnName!='' and columnName!='NA'
```

or if you don't need NULL as well

```
select * from table where columnName!='' and columnName!='NA' and columnName is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT data FROM columns WHERE value = 'NA'
```

`value = 'NA'` supersedes columns with an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE `VALUE` NOT IN ('', 'NA');
```

Comment: I am getting error `Unknown column 'VALUE' in 'where clause'`

Comment: after I add '' around value it gives all columns evenen that has 'na'.

Comment: Make sure you use backticks, not quotes. Backticks are for using MySQL keywords as column and table names, quotes are for creating strings.

Comment: I tried quiry something like this `SELECT * FROM wp_skilllist WHERE First_name LIKE 'M%' and `value`  NOT IN ('', 'NA')`. but I get following error message `#1054 - Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause'`

Comment: What's the actual name of the column that you're testing? Your original question seemed to say that the name of the column is `value`. If that's not it, replace that with the column name. If you want to test all columns in the table, see the dynamic SQL solution in Michał Powaga's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it must be done:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE VALUES <> 'NA' AND VALUES <> ''.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for dynamic query especially in case where many columns are involved in query with same condition.

[Working example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c37a/13)

```
create table t (
  col_1 varchar(10),
  col_2 varchar(10),
  col_3 varchar(10));

insert into t
select  'NA', 'aa', 'aaa' union
select  'b', 'bb', 'NA' union
select  '', 'cc', 'ccc' union
select  'd', 'dd', 'dd' union
select  'e', 'ee', '' union
select  'f', 'ff', 'fff';



SET @q := null;
SELECT @q := concat(coalesce(concat(@q, 'and '), ''), column_name, ' not in (''NA'', '''') ')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='t' and table_schema = DATABASE();
select @q := concat('select * from t where ', @q);

-- select @q;

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

It returns:

```
COL_1  COL_2  COL_3
d      dd     dd
f      ff     fff
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'VALUE' NOT IN ('', 'NA');` I had to insert single quato arround VALUE